# Is it possible to deploy multiple docker images onto a Google Container-Optimized OS (COS) in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-optimized-os

I have a github actions workflow which builds and pushes the docker images to container registry on GCP. Post that it deploys the images onto compute engine. Currently three images are being deployed on three separate VMs. The goal is to have these on the same VM machine.

Tried to Manually create the VMs on the GCP but it lets me add only one image so far. Please help me with the settings or how I can create a VM that can host several Images on it. If not, please suggest a best way to overcome this situation.

Comment: GKE, for instance, run multiple container on COS OS VM. Therefore, it's possible!! You have to create a startup script on your VM that run all the container with a background command. You create a process for each run and that's all.

Comment: In this case, I would not like to use GKE due to the constraints in the budget. I would like to deploy the images onto GCE (compute engine COS VM). Is it possible on a GCE cos VM?

Comment: yes, it's possible. But you have to write the script yourself, there is no built in configuration for multi container

Comment: Could you point me to a source where I could find some details on the approach? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible via `cloud-init`, below is an example.

Add the below custom metadata to the GCE instance running COS, this will start two containers in the same instance.

```
    key: "user-data"
    value: "#cloud-config\nruncmd:\n  - /usr/bin/docker run -d busybox /bin/sleep 1000\n  - /usr/bin/docker run -d nginx /bin/sleep 1000"
```

Then restart the instance to have the changes take effect, and run below commands to test after that.

```
    $ docker ps
        CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
        d7e8a9b707a6   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   80/tcp    fervent_austin
        0b116788132c   busybox   "/bin/sleep 1000"        14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes             elated_ardinghelli
```